# return 2 responses in same body from 2 queries

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

i have this functioning query that i'd like to call some more data without using `JOIN` to the response

**here is my query**

```
$id = $request->getAttribute('id');

$sql = "SELECT *
            FROM users
            WHERE section = :id"; 

    try {
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);

        $stmt->execute();

        $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $db = null;

        if(empty($users)) {
            $response->getBody()->write
            ('
            {
                "error":
                {
                    "message":"Empty"
                }
            }');
        } else {
            $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($users));
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {}
};
```

**what i tried**

```
$id = $request->getAttribute('id');

$tsql = "SELECT *
         FROM teachers
         WHERE section = :id"; 

$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE section = :id"; 

    try {
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $tstmt = $db->prepare($tsql);

        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
        $tstmt->bindParam(":id", $id);

        $stmt->execute();
        $tstmt->execute();

        $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $teachers = $tstmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $db = null;

        if(empty($users) AND empty($teachers)) {
            $response->getBody()->write
            ('
            {
                "error":
                {
                    "message":"Empty"
                }
            }');
        } else {
            $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($users));
            $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($teachers));
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {}
};
```

**the result i got**

i got the data i need but its like unformatted json response, 
usually i get a clean response with "green" but now i got it all on one line in "black"

```
{"userid":"3","firstname":"joe","lastname":"d"}[{"id":"1","name":"jlo"}]
```

**the result i am expecting**

1. clean json formatted response
2. teachers in an array with an identifier "teacher" and another array with identifier "users" with all the array of arrays inside it

Comment: NEVER create JSON by hand. Construct an array and use `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine your data and output it once...

You could try:

```
$response->getBody()->write(json_encode(['users' => $users, 'teachers' => $teachers]));
```

This will let you access your data like: `result.users / result.teachers` and would output like:

```
{ "users" : [user1...], "teachers" : [teacher1...] }
```

Comment: thank you, i have a small question is it wrong that i am doing bindParam and execute multiple times ? is there a better way i should be doing ?

Comment: It depends more on your data models. Most likely multiple queries is the best option if you can't join the tables. A union is a possible solution but only if the table structures are very similar. If multiple queries are problematic, look at caching, just be aware of issues involved with caching.